# Some INNER JOIN in MySQL query

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the next MySQL tables:

```
|provincias|  
| id          | |provincia|   

|municipios|
| provincia_id| | id | |municipio|

|**event**|
|municipio_id|
|idEvent|
|name|
|date_begin|
|date_end|
```

I do the next MySQL query (EDITED):

```
SELECT idEvent, name 
FROM evento e 
INNER JOIN provincias p ON p.id = m.provincia_id 
INNER JOIN municipios m ON m.id = e.municipio_id 
WHERE  provincia = "Iruña de Oka" AND municipio = "Álava" 
AND DATE(date_begin) BETWEEN DATE('2013-07-23') AND DATE('2013-07-26')
ORDER BY name;
```

But I obtain the next error (EDITED):

```
1054 - Unknown column 'm.provincia_id' in 'on clause'
```

Comment: joins go before the where clause

Comment: `JOIN` goes in the `FROM` clause, not `WHERE`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the `from` clause, a table cannot be referenced until it is defined.  You are using `m` in the first `on` clause, before the definition.

The simple solution is to rearrange the clauses:

```
SELECT idEvent, name 
FROM evento e 
INNER JOIN municipios m ON m.id = e.municipio_id
INNER JOIN provincias p ON p.id = m.provincia_id 
WHERE  provincia = "Iruña de Oka" AND municipio = "Álava" 
AND DATE(date_begin) BETWEEN DATE('2013-07-23') AND DATE('2013-07-26')
ORDER BY name;
```

Comment: Ok. I solved the problem, I don't obtain any error, but neither I obtain data...:(

Comment: @vicenrele . . . Try running the query without the clause `provincia = "Iruña de Oka" AND municipio = "Álava"`.  My guess is that this is a character mismatch caused by the accents.

Comment: Also, I have a similar query without knowing "municipio", Then how can I do the query?

Comment: @vicenrele . . . Your original query had `m.id = e.Localidad_idLocalidad`.  I changed this to `m.id = e.municipio_id`, which conforms to the data structure you provide in the question.

Comment: Yes. ok. But that is not the problem. Updated

Comment: @vicenrele . . . I also noticed single quotes were missing around the dates.  `date(2013-07-23)` is very different from `date('2013-07-23')`.

Answer (score 4):

Join statements go before the `WHERE` clause

```
SELECT idEvent, name 
FROM event e
INNER JOIN municipio m ON m.id = e.municipio_id 
INNER JOIN provincia p ON p.id = m.provincia_id 
WHERE  provincial = "Iruña de Oka" AND municipio = "Álava"
AND DATE(date_begin) BETWEEN DATE('2013-07-23') AND DATE('2013-07-26')
ORDER BY name;
```

(And you were mixing non-ANSI and ANSI join syntax, which I've edited to use just the ANSI form)

Comment: I obtain: #1054 - Unknown column 'm.provincia_id' in 'on clause'